# How do I manually beam an NdefMessage with Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nfc

I have my NFC class which I assume people know what it looks like if you are looking at this question.  So OnCreate, I do:

```
mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
```

to be able to send messages and then I do:

```
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event){        
    NdefMessage msg;

                msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
                        createApplicationRecord(this.messageToSend.getBytes())
                });
                return msg;
}
```

to send my message.  and I have some code to receive a message as well but then I want to send another message back while the devices are still in "Connected" mode.  How can I manually give a "send message" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application gets a single chance to send out the message using setNdefPushMessageCallback. Once the message has been transfered you get the completionCallback (if you want to). Afterwards you can't interact with NFC anymore.

Sending a second message after you got your completion is unfortunately not possible with the API as it is right no.

Technically there is no reason for this by the way. Google could add the functionality with ease. It would only take them a day or two. In Android 2.3 there already was an undocumented way to access the LLCP (base protocol of Android Beam) protocol from applications. This is gone since Android 3.0

Comment: After a little more research, I can confirm that for now, this is the case